# Table layout in EXCEL VBA macro breaks if a label entry is missing

Tags: excel, vba, charts

I want to create a chart to show up to four different products and the amount used this week and last week.

The values are created by a different macro and also are used for computation. It could happen, that there are only 3 Fruits in the list (see below).

The table design breaks, as soon as I delete the pinapple (or it is not generated).

I like to keep four entries in the chart for more easy comparision between several created tables, else I would generate the Table with a variable Range.

My data looks like this:

(Range B3:D6)

```
Apple       2    8
Banana      3    7
Pear        4    6
Pinapple    5    5
```

and use the following macro:

```
Sub CreateChart()
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:D6")
    Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(600, 10, 300, 400).Chart
    MyChart.SetSourceData Source:=DataRange
    MyChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
End Sub
```

Is it possible to keep the same layout, even by deleting the 'Pinapple' row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try not to use the default format for graphs. It is better to create your graph with specified format.

You can use instead:

```
Sub CreateChart()
    Dim MyChart As Chart
    Dim DataRange As Range
    Dim i As Integer
    Set DataRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B3:D6")
    Set MyChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Add(600, 10, 300, 400).Chart
    MyChart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered
    For i = 1 To DataRange.Columns.Count - 1
        MyChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        MyChart.SeriesCollection(i).Values = DataRange.Columns(i + 1)
        MyChart.SeriesCollection(i).XValues = DataRange.Columns(1)
    Next i
End Sub
```